# Error on "keys.array" when migrating from Swift 1.2 to Swift 2

Tags: swift

Here is my code which was working on Swift 1.2, but doesn't work on Swift 2 :

```
var dictThemesNamesObjekts = [String:[Int:Int]]()
self.objekts = dictThemesNamesObjekts
let keysArray: Array = self.objekts.keys.array
```

On the third line, Xcode displays an this error: "array is unvailable, please construct an array from your lazy sequence".

Do you have an idea how to correct this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array from dictionary keys in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26386093/array-from-dictionary-keys-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

```
var aDictionary = [String : [Int : Int]]()
let array = Array(aDictionary.keys)
```

or, in my opinion, nicer:

```
let array = [String](aDictionary.keys)
```