# I have an array of dictionary and i would like to get an item from it and use it

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

```
var savedFaouritePlaces: NSMutableArray = [] //matched strings
```

[Here is the info I get and I want to use this items cell for row at index path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9lR7.png)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HeartTabCell") as? HeartTabTableViewCell else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

    cell.heartTabTitleLabel.text = "Wanna use that title here"
    cell.heartTabImageView.image = "wanna use that image here" 

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Basically never use `NSMutable...` collection types in Swift. Use native `Array / Dictionary`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array from dictionary keys in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26386093/array-from-dictionary-keys-in-swift)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `indexPath` to retrieve each dictionary in that array:

```
let dict = savedFaouritePlaces[indexPath.row]

cell.heartTabTitleLabel.text = dict["Title"]
cell.heartTabImageView.image = UIImage(named: dict["Image"])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HeartTabCell") as? HeartTabTableViewCell
        let dictionary = savedFaouritePlaces[indexPath.row]    
        cell.heartTabTitleLabel.text = dictionary["Title"]
        cell.heartTabImageView.image = UIImage(named: dictionary["Image"])
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: This fixed my issue thanks guys
        
        let dic:[String:Any] = savedFaouritePlaces[indexPath.row] as! [String : Any]
        print("savedFaouritePlaces: \(dic["Description"])")
        
        cell.heartTabTitleLabel.text = dic["Title"] as! String?
        cell.heartTabImageView.image = UIImage(named: dic["Image"] as! String)