# How can I access firebase directory names as an array?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to access department and course information for an iOS app for students to buy/sell textbooks.

Right now I have two pickerViews. I'd like to select the department in one and have the relevant courses load into the second. What kind of call can I make to get an array of just the department names when structured as below?

[image: firebase data example]

So here I would want to access an array `["AHSS", "AIE", "ANTH"]`. Then afterwards, I'd make another call depending on the selection. For `AIE`, I'd want the array `["330", "340"]`.

I'm unsure how I can just get the directory names as an array and not the values they eventually lead to?

Comment: Can you show the full structure, what is the parent node of this courses that you have listed ?

Comment: The parent is the root database.

Comment: @tim_d Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/45447180/10150796

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else that might have had this question. @Nikunj Kumbhani directed me in the right direction and I eventually got this which lists the key values.

```
myDatabase.child("departments").child("\(selectedDepartment ?? "AHSS")").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in

            if let myData = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {

                for name in myData.keyEnumerator() {
                    stringList.append("\(name)")
                }
```