# Swift: Unable to access Dictionary keys without this error: Keys(_variantBuffer: Swift._VariantDictionaryBuffer

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, xcode9

I have a very simple dictionary:

```
let dict = ["name": "John", "surname": "Doe"]
```

But when I try to access to the keys of the dictionary I get this error:

```
Keys(_variantBuffer: Swift._VariantDictionaryBuffer<Swift.String, Swift.String>.native(Swift._NativeDictionaryBuffer<Swift.String, Swift.String>(_storage:
```

Here is the complete implementation:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let array = [1,2,3,4,6,5]
         let dict = ["name": "John", "surname": "Doe"]
        print(array)
        print(dict.keys)
    }
```

Any of you knows why I'm getting this error? or how can fix this?

I'll really appreciate your help

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26386093/array-from-dictionary-keys-in-swift ? Use `Array(dict.keys)`?

Comment: Literally just added those exact same lines on my iOS App and it worked:
    `override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        let array = [1,2,3,4,6,5]
        let dict = ["name": "John", "surname": "Doe"]
        print(array)
        print(dict.keys)`
Possibly a build setting?

Comment: @kailoon this is very weird

Comment: @Larme this worked `print(Array(dict.keys))`

Comment: now I would really like to know WHY this happens.. I would expect that a public member would not crash on printing..

Comment: I'd consider it a bug. I'd suggest filing a [bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com).